# Older raid controllers in raid 5 vs. Jbod and SW raid

Tags: centos, solaris, zfs, raid5, 3ware

I'm in the fortunate position to have 6 Supermicro older VOD servers with the following config:

- Supermicro 3U case, 3xPSU
- Dual Xeon 3ghz P4 class cpu (5 years old.. havnt checked the exact type)
- 4GB Ram
- 3ware 9500-8 SATA controller
- 8 SATA SLOTS and a lot of free drives.
- 2GB FLASH Bootdrive

What I'm curious about is the RAID5 performance on these old beasts in HW mode vs. SW on Linux with the controller set in JBOD mode.

I'm thinking on using Centos 5.5 or Ubuntu or ZFS RaidZ on OpenSolaris.

Any tips or Recommendations?

Answer (score -2):

The 3+ years bug with ZFS ARC that still persists, might be something to consider...

http://bugs.opensolaris.org/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6522017

(This one is nasty as it will also go out-of-bounds from the VM limits of a hypervisor!)

Comment: See my comment over here: http://serverfault.com/questions/144639/best-filesystem-choices-for-nfs-storing-vmware-disk-images/163972#163972

Comment: Likewise - http://serverfault.com/questions/162693/my-opensolaris-server-hangs-when-writing-large-files-after-upgrading-zpool/163955#163955

Comment: @user48838 - cross posting the same response to every ZFS-related question, regardless of its appropriateness to the question helps nobody. Can I ask you to only post appropriate responses to questions please as your efforts in the last day have generated a number of moderator attention alerts.