# ZFS System on Production

Tags: database, zfs

Do you know/have any system which works on ZFS such as RDMS? If yes, what is your setup? FreeBSD, ZFS on Linux etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [ZFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS) can support production workloads, such as [hosting virtualization systems](https://serverfault.com/questions/144639/best-filesystem-choices-for-nfs-storing-vmware-disk-images), [running an Oracle database](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris10/config-solaris-zfs-wp-167894.pdf) or general NAS or block-level storage presentation.

What are you interested in doing?

Edit:

This depends on your implementation, but ZFS on [Solaris](http://www.oracle.com/us/products/servers-storage/solaris/reliability-066071.html), [NexentaStor](http://nexenta.com/corp/), [OpenIndiana](http://openindiana.org/), [FreeBSD](http://www5.us.freebsd.org/) and even on [Linux](http://zfsonlinux.org/), have been extremely stable and solid for me so far.

Some other user experiences here: [ZFS Data Loss Scenarios](https://serverfault.com/questions/410551/zfs-data-loss-scenarios)

Comment: I'm planning to run a PostgreSQL instance on the top of ZFS, and I thought that any production environment can give me clues about performance and stability.

Comment: See my edit above.

Comment: I have years of experience with ZFS on Solaris-like platforms. I've only been testing ZFS on Linux (CentOS 6) for the past 4 weeks. It's been *okay* so far. No crashes, but a couple of small bugs... Do you have a particular reason for wanting to use ZFS?

Comment: Yes, my reasons are related with compression. 1- I want to keep more data. 2- I want to see that if benefit of reading less data is bigger than decompressing data on the fly.

Comment: @metdos Yes, that's exactly why I use ZFS (on Linux) on production DB systems. Using the default compression scheme, there's a tremendous benefit with no negative impact. Using gzip, there's a bigger CPU hit.

Comment: Have you ever seen such a behavior like in this thread: https://groups.google.com/a/zfsonlinux.org/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/zfs-discuss/Eb48rC-6xcc

Comment: @eewhite Which DB do you use? If Oracle why did you migrate from Solaris to CentOS ?

Comment: Proprietary database... not relational. And no, I havent' seen that particular issue. I've only been using this with Linux for a month, so I'm still testing. The flexibility and reduced data footprint is worth any performance decrease.